# Apply css :visit to same URL that has different $_GET parameters

Tags: html, css

I have a list view (example, a list of forum posts) of links, and when a user clicks them it takes them to the detailed view of that post. On the detailed view there are Prev. and Next. buttons which takes the user the the next/previous detailed view of forum post.

However, the next/prev buttons have a $_GET parameter on them, so they are technically different URLs from the links on the list view.

Is it possible to apply css :visit to two different URLs, the only difference being a $_GET parameter?

**eg: List view links href's:**

domainDOTcom/forum/post/1

domainDOTcom/forum/post/2

domainDOTcom/forum/post/3

**eg: Detailed view next/prev. links on forum post 2**

Previous: domainDOTcom/forum/post/1?page=1

Next: domainDOTcom/forum/post/3?page=1

I want it so that when a user navigates from detailed view to detailed view and then goes back to the list view, all the posts that they have visited will have the css :visit rule applied to them, but I don't think it can be done just using CSS???

Cookies are an option I guess, but not an idea solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, `:visited`, `:active` match the exact URL string. You can use a common class to style them in the same way.

Comment: Thanks for that, that's what I was afraid of... hours of code refactoring ahead of me, silly legacy code creating the $_GET parameter, but new spec's by management require these :visit links to work in the list views however the user navigates to them. Thanks!